# Magento2 install stalled at 18%

Tags: magento2

I tried to install Magento2 on My local system but i got this error
[image]

Comment: please check xdebug.max_nesting_level value is large  at php .ini.xdebug.max_nesting_level=50000;

Comment: Thanks. but my php does not have xdebug.max_nesting_level at php.ini

Comment: You have to add xdebug.max_nesting_level=500 in php.ini

Comment: Have been added, testing now!

Comment: I'm tried it, but stuck yet!

Comment: How about `max_execution_time`? It should be set to 18000. In case magento's `.htaccess` file is not being loaded, this will have be set in your `php.ini`. You can check it by creating a temporary php file with `phpinfo()`

Comment: max_execution_time, according to Magento's prompt set to -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it may be that updating your database used all your resources.

I had the same issue so tried deleting all the magento files and trying again with the same db and this time it went through

Hope it helps you too

Comment: I found the problem. It's my FastCGI configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Did you authenticate yourself at Magento?

An easyier way to install Magento 2 is to install it via Magerun --> https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2